# Local XML file or External MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, database, xslt

I'm working on a client's PHP website which is hosted through the original company who built the site. There's a section on the site where a user clicks on a country name from a list, the parameters are posted in the URL and the database is queried using these parameters and the holiday packages from that country are displayed on the page. All standard stuff.

Now, as the company who host the website won't give me direct access to the db (understandable, I could be anyone) but want to charge my client quite an extortionate amount for adding a couple of updates, I'm trying to come up with an alternative solution. These are:

1) Create a MySql database on my own webhost and access it externally
2) Create an XML file and query that instead, using PHP and XSLT.

Just to clarify, I'll be manually updating the data myself, my client won't ever have more than 30 pacakges, so it's quite sustainable.

So my question is which should I choose? I'm worried about the speed and security of accessing an MySQL db remotely (and I'm not even sure I can do it with my web host), but would a local XML file be as insecure?

Thanks in advance!

Gem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hosting company should give access to the client - they have all the rights to access and modify their data. Normaly hosts give access to database via phpMyAdmin.

Otherwise, if you put the XML file into folder that is not publickly available then your script could access it and there shouldn't be problems with it.

Comment: Thanks @Riho!

The hosting company are, frankly, a little reluctant to give many details. It took three weeks to get an FTP account from them and they tend to take about the same to do an update. I know that my client won't be staying with them for hosting for much longer, but in the meantime it'll be nice for him to have updates done in a few days, and it helps me pay the bills!

Comment: In this case I would push your customer to swap the service provide little faster :). Tell them that because of their lack of cooperation it is very difficult to provide good service to the customers.

Answer (score 0):

Both methods could be secure if you took precautions to make it that way.

Do you need any other data, or just the country codes? I would say if it is only 30 country codes, and they aren't changing much the XML would be ok, but if there is any more data use the SQL (and it means you can get others to change it too). Obviously check you can have a database, as if you can't it is a moot point!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Riho about the hoster.

Otherwise I would also recommend using the XML file because once this is loaded it is cached by the file system and access will use next to nothing resource-wise. On the other hand PHP opening a remote DB connection each time a script is run (I don't recommend using mysql_pconnect on local servers, much less on remote connections) just to read 30 lines from the DB will create much more overhead.

Comment: Thanks Martin, this was partly my concern with the external DB, even though there'll be really not much data in the tables. If my client then wants to expand his repertoire of packages ten-fold, then I may need to rethink, but we'll cross that bridge if we come to it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using XML+XSLT for small site (and some not that small) and it works good with files up to 2MB, on my experience 10Mb xml files will delay and fail to load sometimes (timeouts).

Most of small sites require about 100kb to 300Kb files.

Of course these values can vary a bit with the server muscle, i'm using a 2Gb 3.0Ghz dual core with 30 sites, not all small and some using SQL with tables of 50000 and 100000 records.

a 2Gb xml data is doing reasonable well with 50000 visits month

Comment: Thanks @neu-rah - I can't comment on the server details, but it's just a small site, and the XML certainly won't be anywhere near 2MB, more like between 25 and 50KB. Am thinking XML/XSLT is the way to go

Comment: true, SQL would be like using a cannon to kill a fly, and the technique is the recomended by Riho, have the xml file on a non publicated folder that your scripts can access